# What is the longest word that can be made using touching characters on a keyboard?

Tags: open-ended

If the keys are touching, you can make them.

For example, `dew`.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few seven-letter words:

> dresser
>  dressed
>  tressed

Answer (score 0):

> Assessed: 8 letters
>  Reseeded: 8 letters. (No, this isn't a misspelling)

Comment: 'e' and 'a' do not touch.